# Is usage of "near to" wrong?

Tags: grammaticality

Is usage of *near to* wrong? For example, which is correct?

> This place is **near to** London.
>
> This place is **near** London.

Comment: 'Near' and 'near to' are largely synonymous and are interchangeable in the vast majority of cases, though 'near' is normally the colloquial choice, 'near to' being a little more formal. Sometimes, one or the other may be the preferred choice possibly for other reasons. 'Our vision is to improve health and healthcare for the people of Oldham by commissioning the highest quality healthcare services, provided near to the patient, is found on the internet and sounds the better choice.' '... provided near the patient' sounds less natural.

Answer (score 5):

Both are found. There are examples of *near to* + place name in both the British National Corpus and the Corpus of Contemporary American English and the 'Oxford English Dictionary' has four illustrative citations, including two which have *near to London*.

Answer (score 1):

*[Near to](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/near_3)* is usually not used before the name of a place, person or festival, but there are examples of its usage in other contexts.