# In the PP 'near here', why is 'near' the head?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, gradability

In [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (p. 640), it is stated (without argument) that in the sentence

[1] *They live n̲e̲a̲r̲ ̲h̲e̲r̲e̲.*

we have the preposition phrase (PP) *near here*, which (says CGEL) has the following structure: *near* is the head (in particular, it is a preposition), and it has *here* as a PP complement. Let's call *near here* the 'outer' PP, and *here* the 'inner' PP. The inner PP (GGEL continues), in turn, is headed by a non-specified preposition (see the next paragraph). In this case, the inner PP consists of just the head, but here is an example where an inner PP has a more complex structure: *from u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲b̲e̲d̲*.

To say that the head of the inner PP is not specified means that instead of *here*, we could have other things, e.g. *there*, *London*, etc. This is in contrast to PP complements headed by specified prepositions, where nothing else could replace that preposition, e.g. *of* in *out of the box*.

Now, my question: what is the argument for this proposed structure of *near here*? Let's assume that *near* is indeed a preposition (which is not obvious, but maybe it's indeed true; see below). Why not say that *here* is the head? Is it just that *near* appears first? Surely there is more to it than that---there are all kinds of cases where the head of a PP is not the first word. Here are some examples (the head is underlined): *incredible t̲h̲o̲u̲g̲h̲ it seems*; *one b̲y̲ one*; *ten years a̲g̲o̲*; *these issues a̲s̲i̲d̲e̲* (CGEL, pp. 631-634). Yes, the default position of the head in a PP is the initial position; yes, these examples are all exceptional in one way or another. By how do we know that *near here* isn't also somehow exceptional? The fuzzy status of *near* (see below) makes *near here* a good candidate for something exceptional to happen...

Also, note that either *near* or *here* can be omitted from [1]:

[2] a.*They live near.* 
      b. *They live here.*

Finally, note that *semantically* at least, either one can be taken as the essential one:

[3] a. *They live near (by which I mean: near to where we are now).* 
      b. *They live here (well, not exactly, but almost).*

I am tempted to say that [3a] is a rephrasing of [1] when *near* is the head of *near here*, while  [3b] is a rephrasing of [1] when *here* is the head of *near here*.

One line of argument, suggested by sumelic, is that *near* always precedes its complement when that complement is an NP:

[4] *They live n̲e̲a̲r̲ ̲[̲m̲y̲ ̲h̲o̲u̲s̲e̲]̲/̲[̲w̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲c̲o̲u̲l̲d̲ ̲b̲e̲ ̲d̲e̲s̲c̲r̲i̲b̲e̲d̲ ̲a̲s̲ ̲a̲ ̲l̲a̲k̲e̲]̲.*

In these cases *near* cannot be omitted, so it is definitely the head.

Moreover, sumelic points out the following sentence:

[5] *If your hotel is near here or near the train station, you can get there on foot.* ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=wEPXCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT64&dq=if%20your%20hotel%20is%20near%20here%20or%20near&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbveeB1vLSAhUBKWMKHYaIARkQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=if%20your%20hotel%20is%20near%20here%20or%20near&f=false))

I don't think [5] in and of itself proves much. But the following sentence, if acceptable, perhaps would go some way towards proving that *near* is indeed the head in *near here*:

[6] *If your hotel is near here or the train station, you can get there on foot.*

It would be hard to believe that the common element, *near*, could be the head when joined with one coordinate, but not the head when joined with the other.

For what it's worth, to my ear, [6] is indeed OK.

Is this right? Is [6] acceptable, and if so, does it prove that *near* is the head of *near here*?

**The 'fuzzy' status of *near***

As a separate issue, there is some doubt about whether *near* is even a preposition in [1] (and if it is not, then it clearly isn't the head). I am still digesting the very interesting answers that sumelic and tchrist have given as regards this topic, and will not yet attempt to summarize them. My original source of the doubt about whether *near* is really a preposition was that, after all, the following sentence is acceptable:

*They live v̲e̲r̲y̲ ̲n̲e̲a̲r̲ ̲h̲e̲r̲e̲.* 
(And [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22very+near+here%22&btnG=Search&num=100&hl=en&tbs=bkv%3Ap&tbm=bks) are some examples in published literature of such usage.)

This would suggest (I thought) that *near* in [1] is not a preposition at all, but rather an adverb modifying *here*. And if this is correct, then it is *here* which is the head of *near here*, contrary to what CGEL says.

(If there is any doubt that CGEL says what I say it says, here is a direct quote, with the *near here* example in boldface:

> The PPs *here, there, now, then* occur as complement to a wider range
>   of prepositions than do such PPs as *under the bed* or *after six*. We
>   find, for example, ***They live n̲e̲a̲r̲
>   ̲h̲e̲r̲e̲***; Put it o̲n̲
>   ̲t̲h̲e̲r̲e̲: I found it
>   b̲e̲h̲i̲n̲d̲
>   ̲̲h̲e̲r̲e̲: You should have told
>   me b̲e̲f̲o̲r̲e̲
>   ̲n̲o̲w̲; He certainly stayed
>   p̲a̲s̲t̲
>   ̲t̲h̲e̲n̲.

Note that the other CGEL examples don't suffer from the same problem as *near here*, because what are claimed to be the heads of the matrix PPs (*on, behind, before, past*) cannot be preceded by *very*. *Before* and *past* can be preceded by e.g. *much* and *way*, but not by *very*.
)

Again, several answers have addressed this issue (whether *near* is really a preposition) already, and I am still working through them. Moreover, as tchrist and others have pointed out, it has been already discussed in other questions,  where [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96118/can-a-preposition-have-the-form-of-superlative) seems the most relevant.

**Summary**

1. Assuming we accept that *near* is a preposition in [1], what argument can be given for the assertion that it is *near*, rather than *here*, that is the head of the PP *near here*?
2. In particular, is [6] acceptable, and if so, does it prove that *near* is the head of *near here*?

Comment: When you've done that, analyse *They live **just by here***. But what good will it all do?

Comment: Related, and probably duplicate of at least one of the following: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/96118 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/47559 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/192319 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/83952 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15982 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/237294 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/170585 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38468

Comment: @BillJ Thank you! Re-reading my post, I realize that at the end, I kind of went off on a tangent. When I started writing it, my question was in fact this: let's accept that in _near here_ we have two prepositions. How do we decide which one is the head? CGEL says it is _near_, but it doesn't give any argument. Note that either one can be omitted. Note also that semantically, it is as natural to read it as _here, but not quite_ (suggesting _here_ is the main thing) as it is to read it as _near (by which I mean near where we are now)_ (suggesting _near_ is the main thing).

Comment: @tchrist Thanks you! Please see the my comment directed to BillJ, just above.

Comment: @BillJ I have rephrased the question to make it clear that the issue isn't just whether _near_ is a preposition or not...

Comment: You refer to "the above analysis of *near here*".  I see some names proposed.  Why does it deserve to be called an "analysis"?  (I think I am wondering what @FumbleFingers wonders above.)

Comment: @GregLee I was using _analysis_ in its meaning 'resolving (something) into its elements'. I've rewritten the text now, though...

Comment: @BillJ 1. You say that in a PP consisting of two prepositions, the first one is always the head. Is that a convention only, or is there an argument for it?
2. So in particular, that sentence ("If your hotel...")  sounds acceptable to you, is that correct?

Comment: @BillJ Whether that sentence sounds acceptable to you would, in an of itself, be valuable information---especially if you are a native speaker, which I am not...

Comment: @BillJ Thank you! BTW, if _here_ is the head, then _near_ is arguably an adjunct, not a complement, and plenty of adjuncts go before the head---AdvPs, AdjPs, etc. Moreover, with PPs in particular there are examples where the complement precedes the head ( _ten years a̲g̲o̲_,  _these issues a̲s̲i̲d̲e̲_---the heads are underlined) (CGEL, p. 631-632). Anyway, claims about what is the head and what a dependent require an argument.  Also, not sure how history can help... e.g. history would suggest that _isn't_ is a clitic (like _she'll_ is), and yet it is not (CGEL, p. 91).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about how to prove that "near" is the head of "near here."
However, I don't find the argument that "near" is an adverb in "very near here" very convincing, for the reasons listed below, so I would default to assuming it is the head because

- prepositions and adjectives precede their complements by default
- "near" certainly precedes its complement when the complement is an NP such as "my house." There are examples of parallelism with "near here" coordinated with "near [NP]": although these don't *prove* anything about the structure of "near here", I think they are weak evidence for it sharing some structure with "near [NP]."

  > If your hotel is **near here** or **near the train station**, you can get there on foot. ([*Rick Steves Italy 2017*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wEPXCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT64&dq=if%20your%20hotel%20is%20near%20here%20or%20near&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbveeB1vLSAhUBKWMKHYaIARkQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=if%20your%20hotel%20is%20near%20here%20or%20near&f=false))

### "very near" seems to be possible even when "near" is definitely not an adverb

> They live **near here**.

If you call *near* in this sentence an adverb modifying "here," what would you say about sentences like the following?

> They live **near** my house.

While it seems (I'm looking at an old question of yours, *[Adverbs modifying nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303520/adverbs-modifying-nouns)*) that adverbs can modify NPs in some circumstances, I don't think that's what's happening here because if "near" were an adverb, I would expect it to be an adjunct and therefore optional in this construction. But "near" is actually necessary for the construction to be grammatical; we can't say

> *They live my house.

So it seems to me that "near" is in fact the head of the complement of "live" here, and "my house" is the complement of "near."

We could hypothesize that "near" can be used in two ways, as a head and as an adverbial adjunct, but that doesn't resolve the problematic use of "very near" that you identified because we can say

> They live **very near** my house.

I think this example, along with the previous ones, shows that we have to say that "very" can modify "near" even when "near" is functioning as a head, not as an adverb.

### Maybe "near" is a weird (gradable) preposition

There is other evidence showing that it is not entirely impossible for a prepositional phrase to be modified by "very." Maybe "near" is just a weird preposition that licenses the use of "very" to modify prepositional phrases of which it is the head (as tchrist says, a "gradable preposition").

We can say things like "**very out** of place/**very out** of fashion." I found an article "[The Language Mavens](https://books.google.com/books?id=my_W8iC7WnQC&pg=PA13&dq=%22very%20in%20the%20moment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi16_Pcj_LSAhVGKGMKHffTCSsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22very%20in%20the%20moment%22&f=false)," by Steven Pinker, that provides another example that I think is similar and some discussion:

> Safire then goes on to rebuke Streisand for "very in the moment":
>
> > This *very* calls attention to the use of a preposition or a noun as a modifier, as in "It's very *in*" or "It's very *New York*" or the ultimate fashion compliment, "It's very *you*." To be *very in the moment* (perhaps a variation of *of the moment* or *up to the minute*) appears to be a loose translation of the French *au courant,* variously translated as "up-to-date, fashionable, with-it"...
>
> Once again, by patronizing Streisand's language, Safire has misanalyzed its form and its meaning. He has not noticed that:
>
> 1. The word "very" is not connected to the preposition "in"; it's connected to the entire prepositional phrase "in the moment."
> 2. Streisand is not using the intransitive "in," with its special sense of "fashionable"; she is using the conventional transitive "in," with a noun phrase object "the moment."
> 3. Her use of a prepositional phrase as if it were an adjective to describe some mental or emotional state follows a common pattern in English: "under the weather," "out of character," "off the wall," "in the dumps," "out to lunch," "on the ball" and "out of mind."
>
> (in *The Workings of Language: From Prescriptions to Perspectives,* edited by Rebecca S. Wheeler, accessed through [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=my_W8iC7WnQC&pg=PA13&dq=%22very%20in%20the%20moment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi16_Pcj_LSAhVGKGMKHffTCSsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22very%20in%20the%20moment%22&f=false))

Now, this is obviously not exactly the same usage as "live very near here."
Pinker's examples of prepositional phrases that can be treated like adjectives would mainly appear in the same environment as adjectives: predicative or preposed attributive contexts, such as "He's very under the weather" or "A very out-of-character moment for him."

The verb "live" does not usually take an adjective phrase as its complement (although I think it is possible, as in "live free") and I can't find any examples searching the Google Ngram Viewer of "live very in *" or "live very out *" (although a Google search did turn up a few examples of "live very out of the way"). So, there does still seem to be something special about the behavior of prepositional phrases headed by "near." But, I think examples like the ones Pinker lists do show that prepositional phrases can be modified by "very" in at least some circumstances.

### Maybe "near" is a transitive adjective

The other option that seems possible to me at the moment (grammarians have probably already thought about it and found reasons to reject it) is to consider "near" a "transitive adjective" in this context, like "worth." *Near* can certainly function as an adjective when it doesn't have a complement, so it doesn't seem so much of a stretch to suppose it could also be an adjective with a complement.

From reading "[New transitive adjectives](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3096)" (Pullum, *Language Log*), it looks to me like the CGEL argument against this analysis would be the existence of pied-piped constructions like "near which...," which are not possible with "worth."

Comment: @sumelic I have rewritten the question to make it clear that it is not just about whether _near_ is a preposition or not... I don't know if perhaps I had better pose it as a new question?

Comment: @sumelic Whatever happens---thank you so much!

Comment: @sumelic Yeah, as I'm sure you've checked yourself, google books has no examples where it is _here_ itself that is coordinated with an NP, which would make for a much stronger case... Still, to my ear, _They live near here or the train station_ sounds acceptable if a bit awkward...

Answer (score 1):

Please also see [John Lawler’s answer regarding superlative prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96183/2085). Mark Beadles also has an answer there quoting the OED regarding *near* as what Mark calls a “sneaky” adverb.

## *Near* as a Gradable Preposition

One way to look at this is to think of *near* as a gradable preposition. Grading prepositions is rather uncommon but certainly possible, at least in speech:

> Jim, could you please reset the clock **above the door** for me?
>
> [*time passes as the task is completed*]
>
> No, sorry, I meant the clock ***more* above the door** than the one you reset.

Prepositions are connecting little function words that describe the relation of their noun-phrase (NP) complement to other words in the sentence, most typically to another NP but sometimes also to a verb phrase (VP). The preposition together and its complement make up a prepositional phrase (PP).

These are all clearly prepositions because they are the connection between one NP (*the clock*) and another (*the door*):

- the clock **above** the door
- the clock **by** the door
- the clock **near** the door

It just so happens that because of its origins as a modifier, *near* even as a preposition continues to enjoy the customary perquisite of modifiers in being subject both to other modifiers of degree and even to regular inflectional morphology:

- He chose a seat **near** the door.
- He chose a seat ***very* near** the door.
- With just two seats in the room, he always prefers the one **near*er*** the
  door.
- He picked the seat **near*est*** the door.

These are not adjectives the way *the nearest door* would be; they come before the entire NP to join it to something that came before it.

Other modifiers like *close* and *far* can’t stand alone as prepositions in their own right but instead need to be followed by another preposition to be used as a prepositional phrase:

- the chair **close *to*** the door
- the chair **closer *to*** the door
- the chair **far *from*** the door
- the chair **farthest *from*** the door

Although you can combine *near* with *to* in this way, you don’t need to, which is what makes it unusual as prepositions run in its gradability.

There are of course other possible analyses of what’s going on here, such has a hidden *whiz*-deletion. But thinking of *near* as a gradable preposition may be the simplest explanation.

Comment: I have rewritten the question to make it clear that it is not just about whether _near_ is a preposition or not... I don't know if perhaps I had better pose it as a new question? Or could you unmark the 'duplicate' label?

Comment: @Araucaria No, it’s because I a word out.